# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Whenever I run this script, I receive the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

It points to "While (objReader.Read())" section

```
namespace MedicalDataExporter
{
    public partial class frmSales : Form
    {
        public frmSales()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dtpFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=blah;Password=blah");

            // String conStr = Properties.Settings.Default.MedpracConnectionString;
            // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection objConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conStr);
            objConn.Open();

            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(8), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 3)) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpTo.Text+"',3))", objConn);

            SqlDataReader objReader;
            objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

            int count = 0;
            while (objReader.Read())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
                    {
                        string s;
                        s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                        //MessageBox.Show(s);
                        if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                        }
                        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "money")
                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
                        }
                        else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
                        {
                            sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < 4)
                    {
                        sw.Write("\t");
                    }
                }
                count = count + 1;

                sw.WriteLine();

            }
            sw.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            objReader.Close();
            objConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(count + " records exported successfully.");
            this.Close();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly the problem is with dtpTo.Text.  What does this look like?  Can you print out the command text to see what the query really looks like?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. sorry but how do i print out the command text? really a freshie learning.

Comment: You need to print it out in C# or use a debugger to see the text.  That is, assign it to a variable and then look at it.

Comment: im running it vb 2010. it throws out "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: put a breakpoint at `SqlDataReader objReader;` line and place your mouse on `dtpFrom.Text` to see the value

Comment: Hi Codingbiz, when i place my mouse on dtpFrom, it shows "DateTimePicker frmSales.dtpForm". And i roll over Text it shows "string DateTimePicker.Text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line that converting your string to datetime causes the exception.

```
   CONVERT(datetime,'"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 3)
```

change it to this

```
CONVERT(datetime,'"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 0)
```

see [datetimeconversion](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) for more info

test this two query on your sql server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '11/12/2012', 3) //this causes the exception
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '11/12/2012', 0)
```

On your code:

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(8), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 0)) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpTo.Text+"',0))", objConn);
```

Best Regards

Comment: I still get the   'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.' error after i changed

Comment: i threw in sql server 2008.' Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'InvoiceNo'.'
    SELECT CONVERT(char(8), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM InvoiceNo WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 0)) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpTo.Text+"', 0))

Comment: change FROM InvoiceNo to   FROM Invoice i supposed that Invoice is your table and InvoiceNo is on of its column. thats why invalid obeject name occurs.

Comment: Ok, after changing that, now it says Invalid object name 'Invoice'
But there is a table with Invoice and InvoiceNo is a column. Spot on for that.

Comment: try your query first on sql query window if its really working before you run your code. SELECT 
 CONVERT(char(8), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,
 InvoiceNo,
 EmployerCode
 ,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,
 '' AS Payment 
 FROM InvoiceNo 
 WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '7/15/2012', 0)) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '7/20/2012', 0))